# Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead & Syntax error on token "(", < expected

Tags: java, android, syntax, telephonymanager

I'm getting two errors stating Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead   & Syntax error on token "(", < expected

on the line:

```
mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

...any suggestions?

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;




    EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
    TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
              //  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
              //  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
            }
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
              //  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The line

`mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);`

is not included in any method. You should put this in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)(which seems like what you want) or a regular method.

Comment: @user2528574 can't say, don't know much about Android. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Should be inside a method, not directly inside class. Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178941/android-read-phone-state) for example implementation.

Comment: @user2528574: In general yes, please refer the question I linked in my answer.