# Android automatic call and cut after connect

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application, I wanna call a person from the application and drop the call if the call get connected successful ( after 2 rings or so ). I can call to the number via this but is there any way to drop the call and get the event after 2 rings or a single ring ?

My calling code looks like

```
String posted_by = "1234567890";

         String uri = "tel:" + posted_by.trim() ;
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
         startActivity(intent);
```

I am new to android
Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't control the phone part for security reasons. Calls cost money so apps are only allowed to say "pls call 123445" and the rest has to be controlled by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the following in a receiver:

```
/** The listener. */
    private final PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                Log.d("TAG", "IDLE");

                if (incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("phoneNumber")) {

                    if (audiomanager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {

                        audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

                    } else if (audiomanager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) {

                        audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                    }
                }

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                Log.d("TAG", "OFFHOOK");

                audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                Log.d("TAG", "RINGING====>" + incomingNumber);

                if (incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("phoneNumber")) {

                    switch (audiomanager.getRingerMode()) {

                    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:

                        audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                        audiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,volRing,0);

                        break;

                    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:

                        audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                        audiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,volRing,0);

                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        };
```

Comment: hi thanks.. Is there is any way to drop the dialled call via application ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing this in Android. However you could use `TelephonyManager` and `PhoneStateListener` to check the phone states. When you got this information you should be able to implement the functionality you need.This post should help you: [Android READ PHONE STATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178941/android-read-phone-state).

Good luck!