# How to define broadcast receiver class and phonestatechange class in mainactivity?

Tags: java, android

this is my phonestate class where im checking phone state change

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";

public void onCallStateChange(int state, String incomingNumber){

        Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Log.v(TAG, incomingNumber);

        switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
                        break;
        }        }
```

this is my broadcast receiver class where connecting with broadcast

```
    public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);
}
```

how do define this in main activity?

Comment: did you tried declaring these classes in MainActivity...it also works inside activity..It doesn't matter where you have declared your class and listener,the only thing that matters is from where you register your receiver..thats it.hope it will help.

Comment: ya thanks... another query that im using "Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);" which will print phone number in logcat,,, but i need to show this number in device as a popup while ringing .....like this video ..... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj1I04fsQQk ....

Comment: you can show it using toast message like this.... Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber+" Calling..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in your android manifest

```
<uses-permission android name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

If you want to listen phone state in your activity than use this instead of BroadcastReceiver class. Include This in your activity :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            String stateString = "N/A";
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                stateString = "Idle";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                stateString = "Off Hook";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                stateString = "Ringing";
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    // Register the listener with the telephony manager
    telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178941/android-read-phone-state).

Comment: thanks for your answer.... another query that im using "Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);" which will print phone number in logcat,,, but i need to show this number in device as a popup while ringing .....like this video ..... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj1I04fsQQk ....

Comment: Use Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Receiving call from "+phoneNr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); in CALL_STATE_RINGING

Comment: I tried this before itself,,,this showing the error "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (CustomPhoneStateListener, String, int)"

Comment: you used YourActivity.this?

Comment: i used that,,no error now,,,but the toast is not coming..im not using any activity(front end) in this project..in call screen i need to print..log cat error is... "10-24 09:05:18.041: I/ActivityManager(293): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10840000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen} from pid -1
"

Comment: First tell me that are there any activity in your project? Are you listening to phone state in an activity? Do you want the Toast to appear only when phone state changes while your app is being used? Tell me these,then only i can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in your Activity, like:

```
private CustomBroadcastReceiver receiver = new CustomBroadcastReceiver();
```

Then add to OnCreate()

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(YPUR_ACTION));
```

But there is no sense in putting TelephonyManager in BroadcastReceiver. You can just add it to your activity like in the answer above.