# Why Android receiver action in manifest file not showing constant PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android studio 1.1.0 and I set api level from 11 to 21 for my project , when i try to set receiver- action in android main manifest file String constant PHONE_STATE not found in suggestions . Can you please help me on this .

[image]

Comment: Studio is unable to show it, but have you tried if it works? Here is some tutorial http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86

Comment: yea i have tried but it not working even after i have register the receive-action with PHONE_STATE, Thanks.

Comment: Have you set proper permissions?

Comment: yes , i think this you are expecting  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: Any help on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178941/android-read-phone-state

Comment: In eclipse constant string PHONE_STATE is showing .